# VS Code cant run C/C++ in integrated Terminal

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

So I am trying to Setup C/C++ in VS Code.
I installed mingw, the C/C++ Extension in VSCode and Code Runner
Code Runner has the following Setting turned on:
[RunInTerminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgk9W.png)

This is the Code I try to run:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    printf("Enter age\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Age is %d", age);
    return 0;
}
```

When I click on the run button from Code-Runner the Terminal generates this output:

```
$ cd "c:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projekte\C\" && g++ test.cpp -o test && "c:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projekte\C\"test
bash: cd: c:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projekte\C" && g++ test.cpp -o test && c:UsersalexaDesktopProjekteC"test: No such file or directory
```

I know that the problem is that there a missing backslashes in the path used in bash

> c:UsersalexaDesktopProjekteC"test

But i cant find a way to fix it.
I am on Windows 10

Comment: Seems to be a known Problam with bash just changed back to the windows cmd and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be an issue with code-runner extension I have similar like Issue but sometimes my code executable runs and then it crashes . So i try to run them in terminal

If the terminal option still Dosen't work , This can be your antivirus causing the issue  . Your antivirus treats the C/C++ executable file as malware  and prevents it from executing It . so Try disabling your antivirus in control panel or uninstall it